# Unmanaged Function Pointer causing SEGFAULT on return

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I have the following method in C

```
void SSL_CTX_set_cookie_verify_cb(SSL_CTX *ctx,
                                  int (*cb) (SSL *ssl,
                                             const unsigned char *cookie,
                                             unsigned int cookie_len))
{
    ctx->app_verify_cookie_cb = cb;
}
```

and I am hoping to call it in C#. I am trying like this:

```
[DllImport(SSLDLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SSL_CTX_set_cookie_verify_cb(IntPtr ctx, VerifyCookieDelegate callback);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int VerifyCookieDelegate(IntPtr ssl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string cookie, int cookie_len);
```

Unfortunately, when the callback runs, after returning, the process dies from a `SIGSEGV`(segfault)

```
    public int VerifyCookieThunk(IntPtr sslPtr, IntPtr cookie, int cookieLength)
    {
        if (!TryGetInstance(sslPtr, out Ssl ssl))
            return Native.FAIL;

        var c = new byte[cookieLength];

        Marshal.Copy(cookie, c, 0, cookieLength);

        if (_verifyCookieCallback(ssl, c))
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
```

What I find strange is that the segfault occurs when the callback is *returning*. So I thought maybe I also need to keep a reference to the return value. So I made a class variable (the class is not GCd):

```
private int verifyCookieResult;
```

Now in the callback I set and return `verifyCookieResult`. Still SEGFAULT.

You might be thinking that there is a bug in the native code, but there isn't. This very same function works in a different context.

Is there something wrong with the way I wrote the code to set the callback function?

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have compiled your C code in 32-bit mode, and you are running C# in 64-bit mode? Are you sure both are compiled/running in the same mode?

Comment: "It works in a different context" is not the same as "bug free". As a common issue: unamanged code is either compiled for x32 or x64 (and sometimes x16). meanwhile MSIL is bitness agnostic, so the same code can run as x32 or x64 - and even x16 or x128 if we ever get runtimes for that. This is decided by the runtime based on teh target settings of the Project. And a mismatch here has caused countless issues of this sort.

Comment: The type of `cookie` doesn't match -- you've got `string` in one place, and `IntPtr` in the other?

Comment: Also make sure that you keep a reference to the `VerifyCookieDelegate` instance, otherwise the `VerifyCookieDelegate` might get GC'd on the .NET side before the C side calls it. That won't cause your current issue, but it's a common gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are running under Windows.

Your probably have a missmatch with calling conventions.
As I see from your example it's set to `CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions):

> Calling conventions describe the interface of called code:
>
> - The order in which atomic (scalar) parameters, or individual parts of
>     a complex parameter, are allocated
> - How parameters are passed (pushed
>     on the stack, placed in registers, or a mix of both)
> - Which registers the called function must preserve for the caller (also known as:
>     callee-saved registers or non-volatile registers)
> - How the task of preparing the stack for, and restoring after, a function call is
>     divided between the caller and the callee

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019):

> The __stdcall calling convention is used to call Win32 API functions.

Try changing your code to std call.

```
CallingConvention.StdCall
```

Comment: Calling convention mismatch could indeed be the issue, but OP should not blindly "try changing" it. He just needs to make sure it's consistent between native (C) and managed (.NET) worlds. Unless he specified stdcall in C (this is not the default and he may not be running under Windows), chances are low it will work magically.

Comment: DllImport indicates that he is running under Windows.